# Load data into custom object from RSS

Tags: apex, integration, data

Can I load the data into a custom object using a RSS feed provided by an external vendor?

Is there any kind of parser/a method that will consume the RSS and let me fetch data from external service?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this currently to track some posts on DFC.  I created a gist here:

https://gist.github.com/3982587

Which is the core class.  It adds data if there is no matching custom object in the system.  I schedule it to hit three times a day, and then there's a util class which sends out an email to let people know new blog posts have arrived.

Comment: OMG !!!! This worked perfectly awesome. I was able to extract all the data I want from the RSS and throw it in SF. Makes life way happier now :)!!! Wish I could upvote one more time on this post

Comment: Excellent to hear :)  I've been meaning to get this out as blog post (is that ironic, not sure) - so good to have someone preview the code.

Answer (score 2):

There's [XML parser](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm) and the [HttpResponse](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm) class can deal with JSON as well as XML.

[Ron Hess](http://www.linkedin.com/in/ronhess) has built a slick parser and shared it on developer.force.com: http://developer.force.com/projectpage?id=a0630000002ahp8AAA

Check these out.

My Developer Edition came with built-in `XMLDom` class. Probably it's their standard code (no idea if I can post it here) but it's kind of crude (from 2007).